# Youtube rss feed to show most popular video?

Tags: rss, youtube

I have two youtube rss feeds but I want the most popular feed to show the most viewed video at the top, how can I do this?

http://www.youtube.com/rss/tag/channelname.rss
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/channelname/uploads

Answer (score 1):

**The feed you want is:**

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/channel/uploads?alt=rss&v=2&orderby=viewCount

This will give you a channel's youtube videos sorted by view count.  You can add `&max-results=50` if you want more than the default 25.  (Also I tend to add `prettyprint=true` and `strict=true` when I'm testing)

http://www.youtube.com/rss/tag/channelname.rss actually redirects to http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos/-/channelname?orderby=published&alt=rss&client=ytapi-youtube-rss-redirect&v=2 which may work for the time being but Google has suggested people move away from the /feeds/base/ feeds.  It's slightly unfortunate too (In the lazy way) because this `/feeds/base/` feed with `client=ytapi...` gives you a nice renderable block of HTML for each entry.