# Trying to sort youtube tagged rss feed to sort on (views)

Tags: php, youtube, rss

im having a small issue with my youtube rss feed()that shows result according to the tag i enter(so i only get the results from that certain topic) as im trying to let it sort the output by the number of views.. I did research and came across the following link [Youtube rss feed to show most popular video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204863/youtube-rss-feed-to-show-most-popular-video) but somehow i cant seem to make it work since the gdata link doesnt work with my code below(im guessing its because its not a .rss link). My question is: How can i adjust ('http://www.youtube.com/rss/tag/bachelor+party.rss') so it sorts to the most views. Probably its just a small change but im not experienced with links yet.. I appreciate you guys very much so thanks in advance.

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://www.youtube.com/rss/tag/bachelor+party.rss');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) 
    {
        $item = array 
            ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 3;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) 
    {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
        echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br>';
        echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
        echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }
```

Comment: I notice you've unaccepted my answer - if something's wrong with it, leave a comment and I'll fix it

Comment: I have it working now.. but i used a different structure to actually get the videos in my website.. I used https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=bachelor+party&orderby=viewCount&start-index=1&max-results=10&v=2 BUT with http and not https..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feed that gives you exactly what you want is 
[`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos/-/bachelor/party?v=2&orderby=viewCount&alt=rss`](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos/-/bachelor/party?v=2&orderby=viewCount&alt=rss)

However, Google has suggested we move away from `/feeds/base`, resulting in this feed
[`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=bachelor+party&orderby=viewCount&start-index=1&max-results=10&v=2`](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=bachelor+party&orderby=viewCount&start-index=1&max-results=10&v=2)

where you can change `start-index` and `max-results` as you wish